# Does Location.hasSpeed() return true or false if the speed is 0?

Tags: android

Does `Location.hasSpeed` return true or false if speed is 0 in Android?
I know if speed is for example 6 it returns true. What about if it is Zero?

Comment: Why don't you try? Or, at least, do some research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if a field is present, internally the `Location` class has a bitmask that has a corresponding bit set when a field value is set.

The default value for speed is `0.0f` so `hasSpeed` will return false with a speed of 0 if no speed value is ever set.

However if the speed is explicitly set to `0.0f` by calling `setSpeed(0.0f)` then `hasSpeed` will return `true`.

Example:

```
val loc = Location("testProvider")
loc.hasSpeed() // returns false

loc.speed = 0.0f
loc.hasSpeed() // returns true
```

Comment: what testProvider is

Comment: hi hello George Mulligan

Comment: @MohamedAli `testProvider` is the name of the `LocationProvider` that the `Location` came from. Since this is a test and did not come from a real `LocationProvider` a named it `testProvider`.

Comment: can it be `true` if location was returned by `LocationManager` or `FusedLocationProviderClient`? even for 0?